# Jenkinsfile/Groovy: Cannot resolve symbol [...] error when attempting to use an enum in another class

Tags: jenkins, groovy, enums

I have an enum defined top-level inside a Groovy class which I want to use in another class that is located in another source file:

```
// File: A.groovy

package com.example.pkg

class A {
    static enum E {
        VALUE
    }
}
```

```
// File: B.groovy

package com.example.pkg

import package com.example.pkg.A

class B {
    void example() {
        final enumValue = A.E.VALUE
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <- unable to resolve class 'A.E'
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to access the enum the Java-way, I get an 'unable to resolve class A.E' error.

Am I doing something wrong? I cannot find any useful information online.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are these files integrated in jenkins, e.g. shared library?

Comment: Hey, sorry for answering so late! Both files are part of a shared library and used by my Jenkinsfile.

Comment: Is it just the enum that doesn't work or can't you use anything from `A` in `B`? In that case you may have to add a `package` statement in both of the files, e. g. `package com.yourcompany.jenkinslibrary`.

Comment: I updated my question for clarification. It is just the enum that is not working - I am able to use everything else just fine. This whole behavior seems very odd to me. I think I will file a bug report soon...

Comment: any updates, solution you came up with?